# Why is root.tracer(0, 0) not doing anything?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have used turtle many times before with tracer off (for speedup reasons) but for some reason now it wont work! code (I'm trying to make a audio visualiser. if possible, please add a thing that will output the current "I" value to the speaker so it will match up with the output):

```
import turtle,pydub
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment

count = -500

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("./input/experiment.wav")

# get raw audio data as a bytestring
raw_data = sound.raw_data

pointer = turtle.Turtle()
root = turtle.Screen()
pointer.hideturtle()

root.tracer(0, 0)

pointer.setpos(count, 0)
root.clear()

for i in raw_data:
    count += 10
    pointer.setpos(count, (i // 2))
    if count >= 500:
        count = -500
        root.update()
        root.clear()
        pointer.setpos(count, (i // 2))
```

I don't see anything wrong. what is going on? if I don't put root.update(), it still updates!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the basic problem is you're clearing the *screen* when you should be clearing the *turtle*. I reworked your code below with this change and addressing some other issues as well.  E.g., turning each screen update into a timer event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from pydub import AudioSegment

SAMPLE_SIZE = 100  # 1 second = 1000 ms

MAGNIFICATION = 10

count = 0

def display():
    global count

    turtle.clear()

    for x, sample in enumerate(raw_data[count:count + SAMPLE_SIZE], start=-SAMPLE_SIZE//2):

        turtle.setpos(x * MAGNIFICATION, sample/2)

    screen.update()

    count += SAMPLE_SIZE
    turtle.setx(MAGNIFICATION * -SAMPLE_SIZE//2)

    screen.ontimer(display)

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("./input/experiment.wav")
raw_data = sound.raw_data

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SAMPLE_SIZE * MAGNIFICATION, 500)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.setx(MAGNIFICATION * -SAMPLE_SIZE//2)

display()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: i found out that i can't use root. turtle just creates a screen already. it worked but now the visualisation isn't synced with the playing audio. I want it to output "i" onto the speakers.